# git doesn't really update my remote

Tags: git, github

My problem is simple, I cloned a remote repository from Bitbucket.
I worked on a file, then I wanted to push it again to the remote.
I make

```
git pull origin master
```

the

```
git push origin master
```

it shows me "Everything up-to-date" but when I go to the remote I don't find the changes !!!
Did I miss something ?

Comment: when in doubt always type "git status", also you probably only need to say "git pull" and "git push" without adding the origin master part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forgot to commit the changes?

`git add /path/to/your/file`

`git commit -m "My changes"`

`git push origin master`

Comment: OP said he only changed a file

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot to commit :)

Answer (score 0):

At fisrt, you need to add changed files to git: 
`git add <file1> <file2>`
Or all files in directory:
`git add .`
Then commit changes:
`git commit -m "Some changes"`
And only after that you push.
`git push origin master`